# Can I read ASP.Net Validator State?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I got some old ASP.NET project to rework, and as this is my first touch with ASP I'm quite not understanding it.

I have some digital form with some 5-6 fields of which, 4 have built in validators attached.

Each validator has client side JavaScript function attached, so when I loose focus from the field it get validated, and if validation is not correct it gives red asterisk and you figure out that something is wrong.

eg one function is:

```
function validateEmail(src, arg) {
        var email = document.getElementById('txtEmail_txt').value;
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
        arg.IsValid = reg.test(email);
    }
```

Now this is all OK, but additional "functionality" is needed that when all mandatory fields are valid, "proceed" button gets enabled.

I do this by binding controls with my check function in '.ascx.cs' file:

```
txtEmail.textbox.AutoPostBack = true;
txtEmail.textbox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(requiredfields_TextChanged);
chkEmailCheck.AutoPostBack = true;
chkEmailCheck.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(requiredfields_TextChanged);
```

Then I set Project value to true if my requirements are correct:

```
 void requiredfields_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Project p = setProject();

        btnSave.Enabled = EnableSubmitBtn(p);

}
```

And I wanted to use

```
 private bool EnableSubmitBtn(Project p)
{
    if (p.ProcedureType == 2)
    {
        if ('CustomValidator3 is valid' && chkEmailCheck.Checked==true){
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
 return false;
}
```

Now, I'm not certain is it possible to get response from CustomValidator3 (something like CustomValidator3.isValid == true, which by the way does not work), or is the only way to rewrite JavaScript function into server side function , and then check that function ?

Comment: check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh9ad08f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: you might be able to achieve this with js only using Page_ClientValidate(), rather than going into the asp code